# Affecting a Child From Another Scene Using Sprite Kit and Swift

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, skspritenode, skscene

I'm trying to teach myself Sprite Kit and Swift. What I'm trying to do is access a child node from an ArcheryScene.sks file and affect that child from the ArcheryScene.swift file. For Example: In my ArcheryScene.swift file I have added this line of code: `let scene = SKScene(fileNamed: "ArcheryScene")`.
This compiles fine and when I say `println(scene)`, it correctly prints the scene I want it to print, this is how I know that ArcheryScene.sks is truly in my `scene` variable. After this, I access a child from that scene by adding this line of code: `let ballChild = scene.childNodeWithName("Ball")`. When I use `println(ballChild)`, it prints the correct child, letting me know that the variable truly contains Ball child that is in ArcheryScene.sks. And now to my problem...

Why can't I say things in my ArcheryScene.swift file like:

```
ballChild?.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
```

or

```
ballChild?.position.x = self.frame.size.width / 2
```

or

```
let move = SKAction.moveByX(40, y: 0, duration: 5.0)
ballChild?.runAction(move)
```

All of this code will compile without errors but when I run the game, the Ball is not affected at all. Also, if I run `ballChild?.position.x = self.frame.size.width / 2` and then print the ballChild position, it will show up as x: 512, which is what it should be, but still when I run the game, the Ball is not affected. This is really confusing to me and I'd just like to figure out what is going on. Any suggestions would be appreciated, thank you.

[image: Here are screenshots of my ArcherySceneSKS.sks file and my ArcheryScene.swift file to give you a better understanding. Notice when I say <code>println(ballChild)</code> it prints it correctly.]

Comment: To be honest, it is not clear how you load everything. If you add 5 or 10 lines of code with less explanations, it could help I think. But, as a general rule, it is better to call methods from another class, than changing a variable. And try to see if it not a dumb mistake, such as a problem with physics, with a simple test in the same class. Once you make the ball move, use the code in a method, and call this method from another class.

Comment: Provide more code, less words

Comment: Did you attach `physicsBody` to the `ballChild`? If not, this is pointless: `ballChild?.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false`

Comment: Yes I did, from the ArcheryScene.sks file there was a drop down bar setting that gave me the option to set the physics body as a circle

Comment: Are you actualy presenting `playScene` on the screen (have you called `presentScene()` with it

Comment: Yes, when I run the game, everything shows up, the ball shows up from the .sks scene, and spritenodes from the .swift file show up, I can do stuff with the sprite nodes in the .swift file, but I can't affect the ball that's in the .sks file. Btw I plan to add more code to this later on today, as requested by the comments

Comment: I have added pictures, I hope this makes my question more understandable.

Comment: You should paste your code into the question rather than using a screen shot, as it makes it impossible to cut and paste code into an answer.

Comment: I'm sorry I just thought it would be easier to visualize, and it lets you see everything rather than just code, I thought it would help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you look at the definition of `Class ArcheryScene` you will see it is a subclass of `SKScene` - so the class you are coding in is *already* your scene.  The `UIViewController` subclass in your project has loaded `ArcheryScene.sks` and associated it with an instance of `ArcheryScene`.

When you subsequently say `let scene=SKScene(fileName:"ArcheryScene.sks")` you are actually creating a new instance of the scene that isn't presented into your SKView. You then modify the ball in that scene, but nothing happens as this is not the ball that is visible.

Instead you should say

```
let ballChild=self.childNodeWithName("Ball")   
if (ballChild? != nil) {
    let move=SKAction.moveByX(50 y:10 duration:10.0)
    ballChild!.runAction(move)
}
```

Comment: Also, you see that the Ball is a child of the parent: "Environment", what if I want to affect the environment itself? For example: `Enviroment!.runAction(move)`

Comment: Ball is a child of the `ArcheryScene` `SKScene`, which in this case is `self`

Comment: If I say `self!.runAction(move)` nothing happens

Comment: That's right - you can't move a scene - at least not with an action.  You can change the frame of the SKView that is holding the scene. If you want to animate a background then add the background as a note and move that.  The scene is like the screen of your TV.  When something happens in a movie your TV doesn't move across your wall.

Answer (score 1):

When you write your following line :

```
let scene = SKScene(fileNamed: "ArcherySceneSKS")
```

You are creating a new scene. So the `ballChild` you are accessing is another one (not the one inside your `self` (ArcheryScene *class*)).

If you `ArcheryScene` class is properly instantiated, can't you access the ball by doing like so ?

```
let ballChild = self.childNodeWithName("Ball")
```

Let me know if it helped.

Comment: Also, you see that the Ball is a child of the parent: "Environment", what if I want to affect the environment itself? For example: `Enviroment!.runAction(move)`

Comment: I can't try right now, but you could either do the same thing as you did with the ball (give it a name and access it) or once you have the ball access it's parent property `yourBall.parent.runAction(yourAction)`.

Comment: I tried this is says: "animating the position of a SKScene has no effect" I've also tried: `self?.runAction(move)` and I get the same message

Comment: Well the error is explain enough, isn't it ? You're trying to run an action on your scene and not a node. Make your ball is attached to another node for example.