# Relating the .sks and .swift files using Sprite Kit and Swift

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, skspritenode, skscene

The pictures below are of my ArcherySceneSKS.sks file and of my ArcheryScene.swift file.

In the bottom picture (ArcheryScene.swift) I have circled in red the code I used to access the Ball from the ArcherySceneSKS.sks file. In that circle, the line: `ballChild?.runAction(move)` will compile but when I run the game, nothing happens to the ball. Why is this?

Also, I said `println(ballChild)` and you can see that it printed everything correct. So I know that the variable `ballChild` truly contains the Ball from the .sks file.

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [Affecting a Child From Another Scene Using Sprite Kit and Swift](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28867217/affecting-a-child-from-another-scene-using-sprite-kit-and-swift)

Comment: I know it's the same question this was just a better way for me to ask it, the first time o asked it everyone was confused

Comment: You can always edit your original question.

Comment: I've answered here and there. Don't forget you can edit your first post in order to add / correct informations for example.

Comment: @lchamp - you shouldn't answer the duplicate - instead vote/flag it for closure

Comment: Dang @Paulw11 I'm sorry I didn't know, you could have politely asked me to remove the duplicate.

Comment: I wasn't being impolite - this is just the process on SO - duplicates are flagged for closure - closed questions are still visible to search, so it may be that a user will find the closed question and then be directed to the answer.  If the question were just deleted that won't happen

Comment: Okay, you're right, I'm new to all this, I just want to try to keep my reputation going in one direction lol, so I shouldn't delete it you're saying? @Paulw11

Comment: In this case you probably can, since it is an obvious duplicate of your other question and there isn't likely to be much benefit in keeping it around, but generally simply being a duplicate isn't grounds for deletion.

Comment: Since it's worded differently and may make it easier for other people to understand and it has an answer that is a correct answer, maybe I should keep it?

Answer (score 0):

When you write your following line :

```
let scene = SKScene(fileNamed: "ArcherySceneSKS")
```

You are creating a new scene. So the `ballChild` you are accessing is another one (not the one inside your `self` (ArcheryScene *class*)).

If you `ArcheryScene` class is properly instantiated, can't you access the ball by doing like so ?

```
let ballChild = self.childNodeWithName("Ball")
```

Let me know if it helped.

Answer (score 0):

use

```
let scene = ArcheryScene(fileNamed: "ArcherySceneSKS")
```

then the object instantiated will be the subclass you desire